# Why wasn't George able to cast Patronus after the events of Battle of Hogwarts?

Tags: harry-potter, patronus-charm

It's said George could never cast a Patronus Charm again, because all his happiest memories were of his brother. But why?

Granted, he mourned the loss of his brother, but he then later got married and he had children, aren't those happy memories?

Comment: #WhereTheRedFernGrows

Comment: I've been unable to source a canon quote from JKR confirming this "fact". I suspect it was made up by the notorious "HP-Facts" Tumblr account.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In short, the 'fact' that George was incapable of casting the Patronus Charm after Fred's death has never been confirmed by Rowling. The earliest attribution I can find for it is on Reddit, going back some 4-6 years but always with

> "I read that"

or

> "JKR said that"

but never with a linked interview or quote.

Comment: Could you add links to these claims made on Reddit?

Comment: Oh ok, I thought it was announced by JKR.

Comment: [example](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/58680)

Comment: https://www.google.co.il/amp/s/amp.reddit.com/r/harrypotter/comments/1o79w1/george_weasley_unable_to_produce_patronus_charm/

Comment: @Randal'Thor - The earliest I've found is from 2012; https://www.reddit.com/r/harrypotter/comments/126yi3/makes_me_want_to_cry/c6sxawa/